# Puppeteer Sharp - Get element containing textContent

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I'm trying to work out how to efficiently grab an element from a page that contains a specific string.

The element is in an `<a>` tag however it's classes/ids are randomly generated.

The only way I can achieve this is by looping over every `<a>` tag and checking if the textContent matches.

`<a>Match this text foo</a>`

I've also tried using the xPath expression however I can figure out how to use the returned elements.

`//a[contains(text(),'Match this text')]`

Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Don't you have some parent element you can ID? so you can do something like `.parent-div-class A`

Comment: Unfortunately not. The site has gone to great lengths to make all selectors dynamic and the HTML is very basic. I'm sure the xPath should be more efficient however I can't figure out how to use the `ElementHandle` thats returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `page.$x(expression)` method returns: `<Promise<Array<ElementHandle>>>`. So you can get specific element by index or just with the destructuring assignment.

For instance:

```
const links = await page.$x('//a[text()="Specific Text"]'); // returns: <Promise<Array<ElementHandle>>>
await links[0].click();
```

or even better with the destructuring assignment:

```
const [ link ] = await page.$x('//a[text()="Specific Text"]');
await link.click();
```

Comment: perfect thank you! I didn't realise the ElementHandle can be used in this manner.

Comment: Do you know how I would read the URL of the tag from the `ElementHandle` object? Im using `c#` for this

Comment: Hey @atoms. What do you mean by the URL of the tag from `ElementHandle` object? Could you please give an example?

Comment: I found it! Was to call `ElementHandle[0].getPropertyAsync("href")`. Obvious when you know how! Thanks for your help!